# How to svn-copy a file over an existing one?

Tags: svn

I have two svn controlled files A and B, where A only contains a few lines and B is huge and has a long history. Now I want to replace the content of file A with the content of file B. But I want to keep the history of (the content of) file B.

What I would like to do is:

```
svn copy B A
```

But svn tells me that A isn't a directory, so this isn't possible.

I could first delete file A, commit and then move B to A, but I don't like to have a revision in my repo that isn't consistent (doesn't compile).

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with the following?

```
svn delete A
svn copy B A
svn commit
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: If you could `copy --update`, then there would be a log record that the copy of `B` over top of `A`.  Just a bit more transparent.

Comment: @will: I don't think this existed in 2010, but ICBW. Anyway, I upvoted your comment for better visibility.

Comment: Is that actually the most 'correct' way of doing it?  I too came here wondering whether I should just delete A and then copy B to where A was, or if there's a better way.

Comment: @Stewart: I haven't worked with svn in years, and am not up to date regarding current practices.